# auto execution jar file after raspberry start up using cron job

Tags: java, cron, raspberry-pi3, headless

i want to auto execution GUI based jar file after raspberry start up using cron job , i got exception such like

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException     at
>   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
>     at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)  at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)     at
>   java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:385)     at
>   javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:189)    at
>   com.mycompany.gui.FirstSwingExample.main(FirstSwingExample.java:43)

my crontab command is 
**@reboot  /usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/Desktop/GUI-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar > /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1**

i also passed JVM argument -Djava.awt.headless=true

please help me

Comment: I don't think cron waits for the GUI to start-up. You should better use the [autostart mechanism of the Raspberry Desktop](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do it is to use a runlevel script rather than a cron job.

Comment: hi cisk please  tell me how write and where it should be put runlevel script.

Comment: I suspect your jar execution is failing cause the X environment is not ready yet when the jar is executed. By using a runlevel scrupt you should be able to run your script at the very end of boot. Try googleing "Raspberry init scripts or runlevel scripts"